# Decorator for async method in class which should run periodically

Tags: python, async-await, python-asyncio

I am trying to learn async and await. I tried writing a decorator for an async method of a class which should run periodically after being decorated (i.e. decorator is what should run it periodically). Here's my code:

```py
import asyncio
import functools

def loop(interval):
    def decorator(coroutine):
        @functools.wraps(coroutine)
        async def inner(*args):
            while True:
                await coroutine(*args)
                await asyncio.sleep(interval)
        return inner
    return decorator

class A:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

    @loop(interval = 2)
    async def periodic_update(self):
        # Some awaits here...
        print(self.a)

a = A(42)
b = A(53)

async def f(l, m):
    await l.periodic_update()
    await m.periodic_update()

asyncio.run(f(a, b))
```

I expected both 42 and 53 to be printed at regular intervals of 2 seconds but this doesn't happen and I only see 42 being printed. Why? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you're awaiting in `periodic_update`, the first call to `periodic_update` will never exit, so await `m.periodic_update()` won't run. You'd want to do something like create tasks instead, then start them at the same time. The code here looking like you're forcing async code to run synchronously.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Thanks, that seems to do what I want. I'll read more about it...

Comment: I'll admit, my knowledge of Python's asyncio is minimal, but I had `asyncio.gather` in mind: "Run awaitable objects in the aws sequence concurrently."